# Change the EAR deployment name in JBoss 7.x

Tags: deployment, jboss

I use Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.2). I have JBoss Tools in my eclipse. I have JBoss AS7.1. 
I have a maven "ear" project. It is called abc-project. It is a maven project from the git repository. It's version in maven pom.xml is 4.7.5-SNAPSHOT. Its Artifact Id is abc-project. When I right click the server (under the Servers tab), and added the project, it is added as abc(abc-4.7.5-SNAPSHOT).

In the ear's application.xml, we have the display name as 'abc'

After I build and publish the project to JBoss, then in the standalone/deployments folder, the ear project is deployed under the folder with name abc-4.7.5-SNAPSHOT.ear

Now in one of our code, we refer as abc.ear while looking for some default labels files. The server starts fine, but it fails to access the project, because it s deployed under the folder name abc-4.7.5-SNAPSHOT.ear.

Can I change the deployment folder or the deployment name of this project?

I would like it to be deployed under the folder abc.ear

Comment: Actually, from what I can understand, you want to have the "runtime name" set to abc.ear. By default, the runtime name is the same as the ear/war file used for deployment but can be set independently

Comment: I could not find a way to change the runtime name anywhere. It looks like Eclipse IDE uses JBoss Tools, or something of its own, to pick up this name from somewhere. Only thing I could see the maven pom.xml. I have to find a way to do this, or I am going to scrap this Eclipse IDE publish option and then go for some Maven deploy plugin...

Comment: Got to say, I'm doing the deployment mostly from the admin console where you have that option in the wizard, or from the CLI with the "--runtime-name" option. I'm not familiar with the Eclipse IDE, sorry !

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? Can you give me some tips on using the admin console to deploy? Or some links to learn... Thx

Comment: Well, can give you the RH support site : https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuration_guide/deploying_applications ... You'll need to register (free) though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever your project is, locate the **.settings** folder for your project. I believe this is the eclipse settings folder. Underneath this folder, there is a file called
**org.eclipse.wst.common.component**

Open this file, and change the name of your project in this following entry
from:

```
<wb-module deploy-name="abc-4.7.5-SNAPSHOT">
```

to:

```
<wb-module deploy-name="abc">
```

Then, remove the project from the jboss server in eclipse under the server tab/view.

Then restart eclipse clean.

Add the project again to jboss server in eclipse under the server tab/view

Publish and restart jboss from eclipse